# How To Set Notification Awaits Processing When The Script is Executed

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script to process duplication of several files by Users, and save these files in their Drive. I Deployed the script using the doGet method, as Web Aplication. While the duplication process is running, I want there to be a notification on the Web page that the duplication process is running, as well as providing notification when the process is complete.

I still have difficulty creating a notification at the beginning, because when I add HTML at the beginning, the next script doesn't run.

```
 function doGet() {
 
 // Here I should include an HTML Notification when the next script runs, so that the user is sure the script is carrying out the process.

 var newFolder     = DriveApp.createFolder('FOLDER APLIKASI PKL KELAS XXXX - SILAHKAN DI RENAME -');
 var folderKelasID = newFolder.getId();
 var folderKelas   = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderKelasID);
 var masterSSID    = "1e8Sn1fRurEUB9l0Xb65iRYLi-yYBfgkRLJcKI2xxxx"
 var masterDOCID   = "107nzTmin2skbXXBTU3vdZsy-ePKY5r7HuhLfngxxxxx"
 var copySSId      = DriveApp.getFileById(masterSSID).makeCopy('SPREADSHEET MASTER  JURNAL PKL').getId();
 var copyDOCId     = DriveApp.getFileById(masterDOCID).makeCopy('MASTER JURNAL PKL').getId();
 var formURL       = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copySSId).getSheetByName("Form Responses").getFormUrl();
 var formID        = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL).getId();
 
 DriveApp.getFileById(copySSId).moveTo(folderKelas);
 DriveApp.getFileById(copyDOCId).moveTo(folderKelas);
 DriveApp.getFileById(formID).moveTo(folderKelas);  
 DriveApp.getFileById(formID).setName('FORM  LAPORAN PKL');

 return   HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

 };
```

Comment: This might be possible by modifying the `Index.html` file instead of having the `doGet()` function push the notification. Would you be able to share the HTML file?

Comment: Thanks for your advice @DuuEyn. The HTML just text notification : 
<html><p style="text-align: center;"><b>&nbsp;<span style="font-size: x-large;">DUPLICATION PROCESS</span></b></p><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: x-large;"><b>FINISH</b></span></p><p></p></html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

In this case, your script is split to `doGet` and `process` functions.

```js
function doGet() {
  // Here I should include an HTML Notification when the next script runs, so that the user is sure the script is carrying out the process.
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function process() {
  var newFolder = DriveApp.createFolder('FOLDER APLIKASI PKL KELAS XXXX - SILAHKAN DI RENAME -');
  var folderKelasID = newFolder.getId();
  var folderKelas = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderKelasID);
  var masterSSID = "1e8Sn1fRurEUB9l0Xb65iRYLi-yYBfgkRLJcKI2xxxx"
  var masterDOCID = "107nzTmin2skbXXBTU3vdZsy-ePKY5r7HuhLfngxxxxx"
  var copySSId = DriveApp.getFileById(masterSSID).makeCopy('SPREADSHEET MASTER  JURNAL PKL').getId();
  var copyDOCId = DriveApp.getFileById(masterDOCID).makeCopy('MASTER JURNAL PKL').getId();
  var formURL = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copySSId).getSheetByName("Form Responses").getFormUrl();
  var formID = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL).getId();

  DriveApp.getFileById(copySSId).moveTo(folderKelas);
  DriveApp.getFileById(copyDOCId).moveTo(folderKelas);
  DriveApp.getFileById(formID).moveTo(folderKelas);
  DriveApp.getFileById(formID).setName('FORM  LAPORAN PKL');
  return "done";
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side: `Index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      const div = document.getElementById("processing");
      div.innerHTML = "Proceeding";
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(res => {
        console.log(res);
        div.innerHTML = "";
      })
      .withFailureHandler(err => {
        console.log(err);
        div.innerHTML = "";
      })
      .process();
    });
  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="processing"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Testing:

When the Web Apps is opened, `Proceeding` is showing in the page and `process` is run with `google.script.run`. And, the function `process` in the Google Apps Script side is run. When this function is finished, `Proceeding` is removed.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your script works fine. Please be careful about this.
- This is a simple modification. If you use this method, please modify the HTML for your actual HTML.
- **When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the details of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. It's work.
I use your modification, and make a Testing.  With the last script on Google Apps Script side,   ' return "done" ', after process finish, there nothing is displayed  in the Web Page.  And I try to modification yout HTML Code  in line :  .withSuccessHandler(res => {
        console.log(res);
        div.innerHTML = "";   to  :  .withSuccessHandler(res => {
        console.log(res);
        div.innerHTML = "Process  Finish";  It's work, displayed Notification when process finish.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying. About `after process finish, there nothing is displayed in the Web Page.`, from your question, I guessed that you might want to show `Proceeding` when the script is running. So, when the script was finished, I removed it. If you want to show other text after the script is finished, please modify `div.innerHTML = "";` to `div.innerHTML = "Process Finish";` in `withSuccessHandler` as shown in your reply.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. Yes. I do that and it's done.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying. If my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: No, your Answer very usefull. I try couple days before I post my question. And you help me to answer and solve my problem, less than one hour. Thanks again.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan By the way, if your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I am sorry, forget to push  accept button. Thanks  @Tanaike to remind me.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for your response! Thank you, too.